# JPA Mapping exception when creating a child element

Tags: java, jpa, one-to-many

I have those persistent entities with their constructors/getters/setters:

```
@Entity
public class Budget {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long budgetId;

    private double totalAmount;

    private BudgetStatus status;

    private Instant created;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "budgetLineId")
    private List<BudgetLine> budgetLines = new ArrayList<>();

    // constructors / getters / setters

}
```

I want to do a unidirectional one to many relationship with this entity:

```
@Entity
@Immutable
public class BudgetLine {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long budgetLineId;

    private String description;

    private int tooth;

    // constructors / getters / setters

}
```

I think I have annotated the entities correctly, but I'm getting this exception:

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   ('dentist-app'.'budgetline', CONSTRAINT 'FKn3er98a66as3vxuj1kij2q040'
>   FOREIGN KEY ('budgetLineId') REFERENCES 'Budget' ('budgetId'))

with this code:

```
private List<Budget> createBudgets(Patient patient, BudgetStatus budgetStatus) {
    List<Budget> budgets = new ArrayList<Budget>();
    Treatment treatment = new Treatment("Implant");
    treatmentRepository.save(treatment);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        List<BudgetLine> budgetLines = new ArrayList<>();
        BudgetLine budgetLine = budgetLineRepository.save(new BudgetLine("tooth", 120));
        budgetLines.add(budgetLine);
        Budget budget = budgetRepository
                .save(new Budget(10, 10, 300, "Comments", budgetStatus, patient, treatment, budgetLines));
        budgets.add(budget);
    }
    patient.setBudgets(budgets);
    patientRepository.save(patient);
    return budgets;
}
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this exception when I'm persisting `BudgetLine` instances, because `BudgetLine` table should not have any foreign key restriction with `Budget` as it's a unidirectional relationship. Any idea on what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. You are right, I understood the `@JoinColumn` in another way, but I tried adding `private Long budgetId` to `BudgetLine` and it's not working...

Comment: You don't need to do that. Thge only change in the Java code that you need is in my answer. If you create the table using SQL and don't let Hibernate create it for you, then you also need to add a budgetId column to the BudgetLine table, and create the foreign key constraint between BudgetLine.budgetd and Budget.budgetId.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I created the property in the Java class because I'm autogenerating the tables from Java code with Hibernate. I have added `referencedColumnName = "budgetId"` to your annotation and it's working perfect, without it doesn't seem to work...

Comment: EDIT: I have read that this is because of the jpa version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping, and table definition, is wrong. The `budgetLineId` column, which is the unique identifier of a `BudgetLine`, and is auto-generated, can't be a join column/foreign key to the `budgetId` column of `Budget`. You need an additional `budgetId` column in the `BudgetLine` table:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "budgetId")
private List<BudgetLine> budgetLines = new ArrayList<>();
```

Also, I don't see why you wouldn't have a foreign key constraint, guaranteeing the coherence of your data in the database, just because the association is unidirectional. You still want a foreign key constraint to ensure that a BudgetLine doesn't point to an unexisting Budget.